# Python subprocess.Popen stdin from file, alter contents as a stream

Tags: python, mysql, subprocess, stdin

I have a large text file (MySQL database dump) that I wish to read into my MySQL server, but I need to change the text. I do not want to read the whole file into memory so I thought of streaming the file and changing the lines when needed.

I have the following code:

```
p = sp.Popen(['/usr/local/bin/mysql', '-u', 'root'], stdin=sp.PIPE)
with open(unzipped_path, 'rb', buffering=0) as infile:
    for line in infile:
        text = line.replace('foo', 'bar')
        p.communicate(input=text)
```

I get the error `ValueError: I/O operation on closed file`. Is there an easier way to perform this?

Comment: `bufferring=0` may hurt performance. I don't see any point to use it here. Consider `gzip.open()` or similar to minimize I/O.

Answer (score 1):

`p.communicate(input=text)` starts the process, sends the text and terminates it.

When the loop tries to send the second line, there is no process left to talk to.

Use

```
for line in infile:
    text = line.replace('foo', 'bar')
    p.stdin.write(text)

p.stdin.close()
p.wait()
```

Note that I'm not sure whether iterating over a file preserves newlines; you may have to send them manually.

Comment: `p.communicate()` does not *terminate* the process. It waits for it to exit (if it doesn't exit; `.communicate()` won't return). Though the result is the same: the process is reaped by the time `.communicate()` returns. Unrelated: you could use `with p.stdin, open(...) as infile:`. On Python 3, you could even `with Popen(...)`.